# Не получается спарсить данные с linkedin

Tags: python, парсер, linkedin

Нужно получить данные профиля пользователя, например: https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimgehrke/

Вытащить всю информацию, начиная от имени и заканчивая интересами.
Сам контент подгружается скриптами, но в `network->xhr` не могу найти нужный запрос, либо его нету, сам уже не могу понять, могу достать информацию только своей публичной записи. `API` тоже не предоставлляет подобних действий.

Использовал `bs4, requests, urllib, grab` ничего не помогло.

Возможно существуют какие-то другие способы?
Нужно спарсить информацию других пользователей

Comment: Воспользуйтесь официальным API, если оно есть.

Comment: как я понял, api поставляєт информацию только об авторизованим профиле

Comment: `import lxml.html as html
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
`
используйте данные либы